# Make correctly a link to an URL containing a random number with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, random, hyperlink, numbers

I'm managing a forum, and I wanted to put in my site a link accessing to a random user profile page.

Assuming that the URL format to access a profile page is: http://www.mypage.com/#m=Profile&user_id=XXXXX (where XXXXX is a number), I tried putting this HTML code:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.mypage.com/#m=Profile&user_id=" onclick="this.href=this.href.split('?')[0]+(Math.floor(Math.random()*(75800000-59438709))+59438709)">Open a random profile. Click here!</a>
```

It works fine, when I click on this link, it accesses to a randomized profile. But the problem is: if I click once more that link, it accesses to a URL with a new randomized ID number juxtaposed with the previous randomized number.

By this I mean: at first time, when I click the link, I access to the URL **mypage.com/#m=Profile&user_id=** plus the randomized number (for e.g. 4542), but at the second attempt, I access to the URL **mypage.com/#m=Profile&user_id=4542** plus another randomized number.

To avoid refreshing before clicking again to get a correct link, what should I do?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are having /#attr1&attr2.

But in the split method you are splitting at '?'
Try using

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.mypage.com/#m=Profile&user_id=" onclick="this.href=this.href.split('#')[0]+(Math.floor(Math.random()*(75800000-59438709))+59438709)">Open a random profile. Click here!</a>
```

The above will give you:
http://www.mypage.com/XXXXX where XXXXX is random number.

For " http://www.mypage.com/#m=Profile&user_id=XXXXX " format use this:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.mypage.com/#m=Profile&user_id=" onclick="this.href=this.href.split('#')[0]+'#m=Profile&user_id='+(Math.floor(Math.random()*(75800000-59438709))+59438709)">Open a random profile. Click here!</a>
```

Comment: As noted by @BrendanLong , have made edits to give the right output. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Or, you can just do:

```
<a target="_blank"
    href="http://www.mypage.com/#m=Profile&user_id="
    onclick="this.href='#m=Profile&user_id='+(Math.floor(Math.random()*(75800000-59438709))+59438709)">Open a random profile. Click here!</a>
```

This will create a link to the hash'ed only part, and always append the proper ID.

Comment: Yes this is best, then only the parts needing replacement are replaced.

Answer (score 0):

You can split at the & using

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.mypage.com/#m=Profile&user_id=" onclick="this.href=this.href.split('&')[0]+'&user_id='+(Math.floor(Math.random()*(75800000-59438709))+59438709)">Open a random profile. Click here!</a>
```